# Swift getter override non-computed variable

Tags: ios, swift, getter, lazy-initialization

In Objective-C, it was really easy and nice to be able to do

```
 - (UIButton *)backButton{
      if(!_backButton){
           _backButton = [UIButton new];
      }
 }
```

In Swift however, when you override a property getter, it's called a computed variable and every time `self.backButton` is accessed, the variable is recomputed. The following example illustrates this nicely:

```
private var backButton: UIBarButtonItem {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width*0.06, height: self.view.frame.size.width*0.06))
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_arrow"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside).subscribeNext {
        (next: AnyObject!) -> () in
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        return ()
    }
    println("Recalculating the button")
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    return item
}
```

The println statement is called every time I access self.backButton. Addtionally, the memory address printed out also changes every time. I understand that that's the nature of computed variables since they are not stored in memory.

Is this an analogous way to replicate the exact same behavior seen in Obj-C in Swift? All I want is a way to instantiate some UI variable once without having to put that code in the initialization method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to probably create it as a lazy variable, that way the initializer will be called one time, the first time it's accessed.

```
lazy var backButton:UIBarButtonItem = {
    let button = ...
    return button
} ()
```

By using an initializer block, you can provide complex initialization of the instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is called "lazy instantiation". 
You can reproduce it in swift using the `lazy` keyword:

```
private lazy var backButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
      let button = .....
      //....
      return button
 } ()
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work because you need `UIBarButtonItem = {` and then () at the bottom. @David got it right